# Problems using extensions in tel: hyperlinks on Android 4

Tags: android, html, mobile-website, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

We have a mobile web site with some phone number links, like this:

href="tel:12345678,123"

This works fine on most devices, but it appears it doesn't work on many/all Android 4 devices. The extension simply doesn't appear in the dialer when you tap the link.

Anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), the `tel:` scheme supports [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966). Reading these RFCs is a bit like reading cuneiform on clay tablets, but from what I can tell, your syntax is not part of that standard. It looks like you would want `tel:12345678;ext=123`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to the developer, this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested both methods with Android 2.1.

`tel:5553334444;ext=123` ends up dialing an extension of 358123 instead of 123 because it converts *ext* into a number instead.

The right way is to use comma.

`tel:5553334444,123`

Tried that with our extension here and it connected me through immediately. It first dials the number, then pauses, and then punches in the extension 123 on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can consider since `tel:5553334444;ext=123` only works for less than 4.0 and `tel:5553334444,123` works for 4.0+ would be to check the user agent and put out the appropriate one.