# How do I give option to dial an extension in Tel: link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, tel

While putting a tel link as `<a href="tel:+91123456789,,123">Dial</a>` and clicking it from a mobile browser, only initial number gets transferred to dialer and not the commas or extension. I've tried `p`, `w` and `;ext=` as well but nothing is working. `p` and `w` change to '7' and '9' respectively.

Tested using Moto X 1st Gen.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), the `tel:` scheme supports [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966). Reading these RFCs is a bit like reading cuneiform on clay tablets, but from what I can tell, your syntax is not part of that standard. It looks like you would want `tel:+91123456789;ext=123`.

**UPDATE:** Something you can consider since `tel:+91123456789;ext=123` only works for less than 4.0 and `tel:+91123456789,123` works for 4.0+ would be to check the user agent and put out the appropriate one.

```
<a href="tel:+91123456789;ext=123">Dial</a> //Less than 4.0
<a href="tel:+91123456789,123">Dial</a>     //Greater than 4.0
```

Source: [Problems using extensions in tel: hyperlinks on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838775/problems-using-extensions-in-tel-hyperlinks-on-android-4)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion brother but I've mentioned and I again checked that none of the above formats is working.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of this is [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-3) which says you need to use `;ext=` at the end:

> `extension            = ";ext=" 1*phonedigit`
>
> Phone extensions identify stations behind a non-ISDN PBX and are
> functionally roughly equivalent to ISDN subaddresses.  They are
> identified with the 'extension' parameter.

You say you have tried this tho, so it may be that your browser only supports the older obsolete [RFC 2806](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806#section-2.2), which RFC 3966 replaces.

For this older RFC, it looks like you need to set a post-dial sequence, using `;postd=`:

> `post-dial             = ";postd=" 1*(phonedigit / dtmf-digit / pause-character)`
>
> Phone numbers can also contain a post-dial sequence. This
> is what is often used with voice mailboxes and other services that
> are controlled by dialing numbers from your phone keypad while the
> call is in progress.