# Click to call with options, is that possible?

Tags: html, phone-number

We need to have a link which will dial an 800 number and also select '1' in the options

```
<a href="tel:800-000-0000" target="_self">800-000-0000</a>
```

This above link just dials the number but how do I select option '1' as well?
 Please help.

Comment: Don't think that's possible. You'd possibly have to wait for some delay as well.

Comment: @Mario thanks for the response. I didnt understand the second part, which delay are you talking about?

Comment: I think you'd like to send the `1` to some kind of answering machine? You can't be sure when it's actually listening.

Comment: I saw a couple of ways to do this, but it is still not working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153574/how-do-i-give-option-to-dial-an-extension-in-tel-link