# How can I make a HTML Phone call with an extension number on Android via a website?

Tags: android, html

How can I make a HTML Phone call with an extension number on Android via a website?

I tried making a link like this

`<a href="tel:+18002299331,1234">Call Me!</a>`

The link will put the first 10 digits in the android phone app but it will leave out the extension.  I tried this on android 5.0 and 6.0. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Problems using extensions in tel: hyperlinks on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838775/problems-using-extensions-in-tel-hyperlinks-on-android-4) one way of putting an extension number is using something like `tel:12345678;ext=123`

Another answer in that question says that this only work in some Android versions.

Comment: I tried that as well, it does not work on version 5 or 6. I have not tested it on 4 though.